# listener that is suitable for performance testing

Tags: database, jmeter, listener, performance-testing

I am doing database performance testing using jmeter, for the assessment I want to see the results of Throughput, Latency, Resource utilization and Error Rate. for that what are the right listeners to see the value of the points above

Comment: I typically use the Symmary Report and/or the View Results in Table. See my notes at [JMeter SQL Database Load Test](https://bitbucket.org/impalerthe/k2/src/7b37052251e3397852a0cc3570f6ef66732e7c4a/jmeter/jmeter-sql-load-test.md).

Answer (score 0):

All listeners are "suitable" for performance testing just make sure to have them disabled during the test run.

The main idea is that you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
```

and once your test is complete you can open `result.jtl` file with the listener of your choice and see the metrics.

1. Throughput and Error Rate - [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)
2. Latency - [Latencies over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LatenciesOverTime/) or [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
3. Resource Utilization - [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the profiler report for your database?